# Selections and localization with Smarty

Tags: php, localization, smarty

I'm trying to implements selection lists using Smarty and I'm aware of the [{html_options}](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.html.options.php). The application must support localization (which I implemented as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883474/php-includeonce-handling-of-imports-i-e-for-configuration-files)).

**Is it possible to combine the two?**

*I'm currently handling it by parsing through the items with `{section name=i loop=$list}` and "manually" generating the HTML code (handling the translation with `{eval}`). I don't like the solution, but couldn't find a better way yet.*

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a custom Smarty plugin that calls your existing translation code.

Either a [modifier](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/plugins.modifiers.php) that allows variables to be passed translation eg

```
{$myvar|translate}
```

Or a [block function](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/plugins.block.functions.php) like

```
{translate}This text{/translate}
```